# cpanel virtual host problem

Tags: virtualhost

Hi have my own website hosted in cpanel (linux). I want to do some testing on website with httpd.conf file modification. but I don't have access on this file. Can any body help me, how I can use virtual host for my website without the server side limitation. I want use redirect map and redirect rule on my website and for I need  virtual host modification. Please help me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

<sup><sub>(you don't state your level of access to the server and cPanel in your question, so I've assumed that you are a base user or reseller, rather than root or other admin)</sub></sup>

You can't edit the httpd configuration files unless you have root access (or similar privedges by other means) on the server. Even then it is generally recommended on systems like cpanel that you leave such configuration alone as cpanel may revert your changes next time it reconfigures itself due to update.

You may be able to put the rewrite directives into `.htaccess` files though. This can be turned on/off by server operators, so you are not guaranteed to have access to the feature, but if it does work then your changes are very unlikely to be reverted during a system software update. http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html is one example, you should find more if you search for `htaccess rewrite` or similar.

I've not used cPanel for some time, but I seem to recall there was a section of its interface specifically for URL rewriting (used for hot-link blocking and similar), though this may have been in the root/reseller areas of the interface only. It would be worth scanning through the available options in your control panel and/or asking your host if any such features are enabled for your account.